# How to perform currency formatting with string interpolation in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-core, formatting

Is it possible to perform string formatting using c#'s string interpolation with a specific **CultureInfo**?

For example if you are in a en-US System and want the number to be formatted with pt-PT how to I achieve that with string interpolation?

Comment: Don't know if this can be helpful, but why not setting the whole thread culture?
You can use instruction like this one:
`CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;`

Or just set the whole thing to culture pt-PT

Comment: @Emanuele thank you, I know that already, but I don't want to change the thread culture at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Interpolated strings can be converted to `FormattableString`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#implicit-conversions-and-how-to-specify-iformatprovider-implementation), which can be formatted with a `IFormatProvider`:

```
var formattableString = (FormattableString)$"{1.1:C}";
var result = formattableString.ToString(new CultureInfo("pt-PT"));
// "1,10 €"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture?view=netcore-3.1) for specifying the culture and the [`C formatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#CFormatString) for converting the value into a string with a currency.

```
double amount = 50.5;
string str = $"{amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-PT"))}";
```